# I want to give my party the Prestidigitation spell. How can I?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

My party consists of: Paladin, Barbarian, Ranger, Rogue.

I've been digging through scroll and magic item rules because I thought I could find the answer to my question, but I haven't. I want to give the ability to cast prestidigitation to my party.

Is there any way any of these characters could cast this spell? (Either through scroll or maybe some magic item that allow them the use of the spell even as a cantrip or X times per day?)

Comment: What level and archetype are they, specifically the Rogue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the DM allows feats you can let one or more of them take the Magic Initiate feat at the appropriate time. Either through natural progression or through the "Additional Training" detailed in the DMG.

Assuming your party has not already chosen their archetypes Arcane Tricksters (Rogue) gain cantrips so they can choose it as one as well.

Another option for an established party, but also optional so check with the DM, is multi-classing to a class that has it as an option on its list. Paladin can synergize pretty well with Sorcerer or Warlock as an example, and Wizard or Sorcerer isn't a bad choice for Rogue assuming they have the appropriate prerequisite ability scores.

All of the above have an opportunity cost to the PC. If prestidigitation is somehow a crucial plot point I would suggest an item instead. This item will have to be Homebrew but could model the minor magic items found in Xanathar's Guide to Everything (this is, again, optional so check with the DM). Ideas could be simply a wand/staff that allows it to be cast x times per dawn or unlimited.

You had mentioned scrolls prior to the edit, that would be a one shot item, and only really useful if the Rogue were an Arcane Trickster or Thief (Use Magic Device).

Just to round things out, if a new character is created High Elves get a free cantrip on creation but I leave this as a foot note since it is obvious that your party is already established.

Comment: A 13th level Thief could attune to a Hat of Wizardry (XGtE p137, common) but would still have to pass a DC 10 Int(Arcana) to cast a Wizard cantrip (one attempt per long rest).

Comment: @NickBrown True, I don't have my books during the day, and since the OP still has not provided Archetypes and level I will just have to leave it as is right now. Seems an awful waste for a 13th level Rogue to attune to something like that though... would have to be desperate or starved for items at that stage I should think :).

Comment: Definitely not a great benefit for being such a high-level and attuning to an inferior item for a chance at a cantrip, but it is possible.  If I were trying to get a party to use a cantrip they didn't have I would make up Gloves of Prestidigitation or Gloves of Mage Hand or something.

Answer (score 4):

**There are many ways to give them cantrips but the RAW is limited to these as far as i know:**

If the rogue chooses the Arcane Trickster he gets the ability to cast mage hand and learn two additional cantrips from the wizard spell list which includes Prestidigitation. *PHB 97-98*

If the DM allows the players to take feats any character can get the Magic Initiate feat, allowing the character to learn 2 cantrips from a class enabling them to acquire the Prestidigitation spell. *PHB 168*

**There are more ways if you don't mind homebrewing:**

Especially if you are the DM and the ability to cast Prestidigitation is a game changer for the current scenario/quest. Either way, if you want your players to have something... Give it to them.

I thought of two *magical* items as i wrote this answer:

> **The Wizards' Hat**
>
> While attuned to this item you rapidly grow a magnificent white beard. You can cast the Prestidigitation cantrip (once? twice? no limit?).

Maybe add in some other stuff if anyone is actually interested in spellcasting.

> **Potion of Wizarding**
>
> While affected by this potion you can cast the Prestidigitation cantrip. Add your proficiency bonus to Intelligence(Arcana) checks, double if you are already proficient in Arcana.

Also you can give them a weaker version of an Ioun Stone, Reserve. *DMG 176*

It basically stores spells so you can cast them later. This would be the easiest solution if the players only need a couple of prestidigitation casts before accomplishing their goal.

**Note:**

By RAW spell scrolls wouldn't help the party as they need to have the cantrip in their class spell list to use the scroll:

> A spell scroll bears the words of a single spell, written in a mystical cipher. If the spell is on your class's spell list, you can use an action to read the scroll and cast its spell without having to provide any of the spell's components. Otherwise, the scroll is unintelligible.

Answer (score 3):

**Add an NPC who knows Prestidigitation**

If you're trying to give your party access to Prestidigitation for some mechanical reason specific to your campaign, a simple way is to introduce an NPC to the party who knows the cantrip (if you actually want your players using it, refer to one of the other answers).

If the party only needs the cantrip for a segment of the campaign, you can always have the NPC leave or die when your party finishes the segment.

Answer (score 2):

Given how useful the spell is for everyday purposes it would not surprize me if someone build a magic item to use it, even for something as simple as cleaning the kitchen or shop. So you could just have them find homebrewed items that grants it or more likely one of its effects. a magical lighter, a self heating stew pot, or brush that magically cleans seems like a fairly simple magical items, the kind apprentices might make for practice even and thus might be fairly cheap.